# how to set auto column and row inTableLayout

Tags: android, tablelayout

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="*"
    android:id="@+id/linear_avatar">

</TableLayout>
```

Hi
how i can set auto number for column and row in TableLayout

Comment: what's going on ??? is there  any way to do this ??